# How to identify and switch to the frame in selenium webdriver when frame does not have id and title

Tags: c#, selenium

Can anyone tell me how I can identify and switch to the iframe which hasn't title and id.
I need to get into this frame in order to find another element in this frame for sending some text.

```
<div class="sceditor-container" style="width: 1359px; height: 300px;">
  <div class="sceditor-toolbar">
  <iframe frameborder="0" src="javascript:false" style="width: 1349px; height: 261px;">
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html style="height:100%">
       <head>
             <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
             <link href="" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
       </head>
      <body contenteditable="true" style="height:88%">
        <div> </div>
      </body>
     </html>
 </iframe>
```

For this I wrote code:

```
WebDriver.SwitchTo().Frame(WebDriver.FindElement(By.TagName("iframe")));
WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body")).SendKeys("text");
WebDriver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

But WebDriver can't find iframe element and as a result can't send text value into iframe element.

Comment: Is it throwing an exception related to **"No Frame found"**?

Answer (score 5):

To click and sendkeys use below code

```
WebElement loc=driver.findElement(By.XPath("html/body"));
 Actions a= new Actions(driver);
 a.click(loc).sendKeys("emailBody").perform();
```

To set the text in the iframe element you will have to first copy the text from the Body tag

```
WebElement emailBody = driver.findElement(by.xpath("/html/body"));
emailBody.getText();
```

Once Text is copied into emailBody, you can use it with element inside frame as below

```
WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body")).SendKeys(emailBody);
```

Try below code to switch to frame and see what happens

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'javascript:false')]")));
```

Also you can try to access frame using its index, try

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

Comment: After some waiting time I recieved:  OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException : Timed out after 60 seconds
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div/div/span[contains(text(),    'Preview')]/../.."}                                                 So the code for this element was: 
WebDriver.SwitchTo().Frame(WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[contains(@src,'javascript:false')]")));                             WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body")).SendKeys(emailBody);
WebDriver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();

Comment: I posted HTML above, in my question

Comment: Ah yes Prview is the button which I should click after I've filled this element in the iframe. But it receives error because validation says: "Email Body is required". So i need to fill this iframe element, but as I mentioned I can't find it

Comment: It seems like Webdriver can locate this iframe element but webdriver can't set text into this element...

Comment: At this moment it's not available.  To answer on your preiveus questions:  Email Body is the text which user can see above the form which he should fill. So iframe element is a place on the page where user should set some text content. So the code            WebDriver.SwitchTo().Frame(0)    or    WebDriver.SwitchTo().Frame(WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[contains(@src,'javascript:false')]")))    working. But the problem is that Web driver can't set text in the iframe:  WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body")).SendKeys(emailBody);

Comment: Html for this element, in the BODY you can see text which I wrote from browser:     <iframe frameborder="0" src="javascript:false" style="width: 1349px; height: 261px;">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height:100%">
<head>
<body contenteditable="true" style="height:88%">
Text for text
<br>
<div> </div>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>

Comment: No, I just explained to you...Email body is just title for the form element. All I need is set text in the described iframe element

Comment: I don't understand, what I should copy if by defoult there is not any text in the body tag?   I have defined variable:                     string emailBody = "Test Email Body";    - this is the text which my automated test should send to the iframe element whith this code:                      WebDriver.SwitchTo().Frame(WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[contains(@src,'javascript:false')]")));                 WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body")).Click();                 WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body")).SendKeys(emailBody);
WebDriver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();

Comment: Can you give some wait time between Click() and SendKeys() action and see what happens?

Comment: Can you also try the updated code of the Top to perform click and sendKeys action?

Comment: Ye, I added  Sleep(10) betweeb Click and SendKeys, and also I tried your code...but it didn't help...

Answer (score 0):

I used ChromeDriver for a while but recently switched to phantomjs as I was having problems with ChromeDriver hanging inexplicably.  phantomjs (if my research is right) works almost exclusively via Javascript by (this is a bit more of a guess than hard facts) injection.  So, how's that relevant?  Well I discovered that you can run your own JS against the DOM of a page you've loaded.  So I threw your source into https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output and tried to run some xpath against it and it threw up.  After closing your meta and link tags with a forward slash, it and then adding closing div tags for the opening pair, it then evaluated my xpath as expected.
Can you correct these or is this source external to you?  If you can, I'd do so.
Then try running a Jscript using

```
driver.ExecuteScript("Your javascript here..");
```

Put the code to set the value of your div object in the script.  I don't have a sample handy but use an appropriate selector with

```
driver.querySelector("tag.className..").innerHTML = "Your Keys";
```

In playing around with this using the Console in chrome, I was still having issues.  But it's my strong suspicion that malformed HTML is your culprit.  If you've solved this I'd love to see the answer.  Cheers!