# Selenium C# How do I find the correct frame to focus on and find the element?

Tags: selenium

My problem is that I have multiple frames on the page that cause two issues. The first issue is that when I try and use xpath or CSS to locate the element there is a dynamic id used. I have copied the selector and xpath from the page below.

```
<iframe height="0" width="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://loginalpha.konnexme.com/identity/connect/checksession" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px; left: -1000px; top: -1000px;"></iframe>


<iframe frameborder="0" src="Screens/People/Client/Client.aspx?x=0.6451605191939831&amp;sEntityID=&amp;sMode=Browse&amp;sData=&amp;sAuthCode=" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>

<div class="dhx_tab_element dhx_tab_element_inactive" tab_id="t7" style="width: 64px; height: 26px; top: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); left: 468px;"><span>Medicare</span><div style="background-image: url(&quot;codebase/imgs/dhx_blue/dhx_blue_top.gif&quot;); background-position: 0px -185px; top: 0px; width: 2px; left: 0px;"></div><div style="background-image: url(&quot;codebase/imgs/dhx_blue/dhx_blue_top.gif&quot;); background-position: 0px -275px; top: 0px; width: 2px; right: 0px;"></div><div style="background-image: url(&quot;codebase/imgs/dhx_blue/dhx_blue_top.gif&quot;); background-position: 0px -230px; top: 0px; width: 60px; left: 2px;"></div></div>
```

My next issue is finding the correct frame to focus on. When I inspect the page there is no id or name for the frames. What it looks like to me is that each frame is treated as an individual window. Here is the only iframe is see on the inspected page.

```
<iframe frameborder="0" src="Screens/People/Client/Client.aspx?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
```

I'm new to selenium and could really use some help thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Medicare

[image]

Comment: See this post for switching to an iframe:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27398803/how-to-identify-and-switch-to-the-frame-in-selenium-webdriver-when-frame-does-no

Comment: @Overdrive What language are you using (Python, Java, C#)? And, can you post the full page source, or at least more than just the `iframe` element? You imply there are multiple `iframe` elements on the page but you only posted HTML for one. Can you clarify what your page source looks like, or post a link?

Comment: ...and post the current code you are using and the error message received.

Comment: Thank you Jortega and Christine, I found a similar issue that had code to count how many iframes were on the page Christine but when I inspect the element that's the only iframe I see. I read the issue in the link that is similar to my problem Jortega posted. I'm currently getting this error "No such element unable to find element" @JeffC

Comment: No such element means your selector did not locate anything, and needs to be updated. But we cannot help you update it because we don't know what the page looks like.

Comment: @Christine I'm not sure what part of the code you need. This is what I get when I inspect the element I'm trying to find. It helped me find all the other elements. The page is pretty big I can take multiple screen shots. I don't know a better way to display the code.

Comment: The screenshot helps a little bit (although copy and pasting the HTML is better so that we can test it ourselves) but I still can't see any `iframe` element that you've mentioned in your problem description. I'm also not sure what exactly you are trying to do with your code. What element are you trying to locate here?

Comment: @Christine I have added screen shots to show the full page. Sorry I was trying to get both screen shots together and lost the ability to zoom. But there are two iframe elements in the screen shots one is highlighted. What I'm trying to do is inspect an element that has the text Medicare in the tab(it's the line the cursor is on in the first screen shot). I want to be able to click the button which will result in displaying more information.

Comment: Now I can see `iframe` elements, but I don't see where the `Medicare` text falls under the tree. Instead of posting screenshots, can you just use Inspect Element -> Right click on top-most `<html>` node -> Copy outerHTML. Then just edit your question and paste that.

Comment: @Christine I tried to do that but I reached the character limit pasting, is there a certain part of the code you don't need?

Comment: There are two things -- 1. Context of the two `iframe` elements -- mostly trying to get an idea if they are nested, and which one is nested higher up. And 2. Context of the "Medicare" element in relation to the `iframe` element it is nested under. So, first sample can start at highest-level `iframe`, and end at the 2nd nested `iframe`. 2nd sample can start at `iframe` that is above Medicare element, and end at Medicare element itself. I can edit your question to help with formatting if need be. Thanks for taking the time to add these details.

Comment: @Christine I took better screen shots of the code, there are in order from top to bottom of page and here is the outer HTML for the iframe and medicare tab that I found. They are in order of the screen shots taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your screenshots, it looks like you have two nested `iframe` elements, and your desired `span` element exists inside the 2nd nested `iframe`. We will need to perform two `switch_to_frame` operations before locating the `span` element:

```
// declare WebDriverWait
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);

// switch into first (top-level) frame
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.XPath("//iframe[contains(@src, 'loginalpha.konnexme')]"));

// switch into 2nd nested frame
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.XPath("//iframe[contains(@src, 'Screens/People/Client/Client.aspx')]"));

// now the medicare element is visible to webdriver
var medicareElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[span[text()='Medicare']]"));

medicareElement.Click();
```

The above code starts by switching into the top-level `iframe`. This allows `WebDriver` to see the 2nd nested `iframe`, which is switched to on the next line of code. Now, all the items under the 2nd `iframe` should be visible to `WebDriver`, and you should be able to locate your `Medicare` element. All of the statement calls invoke `WebDriverWait` to ensure the element exists before trying to interact with it.

Note: This code locates the `div` element one level above `Medicare`, because that's probably the one that needs to be clicked. This selector may need to be modified depending on which element needs to be clicked -- your original CSS selector strategy may work here.

Comment: Great learning experience for me, I know now spare no details. Again thank you so much @Christine